# PG::Error: ОШИБКА: нет доступа к отношению "название таблицы" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, сервер

Как решить проблему? и как посмотреть лог puma? не могу найти нигде.

Ситуация такая: хочу сделать staging для проекта.

1) сделал деплой проекта на тестовый сервер (raspberry).

2) Восстановил базу (postgresql) из бэкапа с продакшн. Миграции не накатывал, их 1000 и очень много отваливается, приходится лезть и комментировать код, да и это не вариант.

Использую nginx, который смотрит на puma.
Запускаю

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///home/ivanov/www/ivanov/current/apps/www/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

и вываливается ошибка:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /home/ivanov/www/ivanov/releases/20170622115720/apps/www/config/environment.rb:9)
/home/ivanov/www/ivanov/releases/20170622115720/apps/www/config/initializers/bypass_ssl_verification_for_open_uri.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
/home/ivanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/home/ivanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
! Unable to load application: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ОШИБКА:  нет доступа к отношению site_configs
: SELECT  "site_configs".* FROM "site_configs"  LIMIT 1
/home/ivanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `async_exec': PG::Error: ОШИБКА:  нет доступа к отношению site_configs (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
: SELECT  "site_configs".* FROM "site_configs"  LIMIT 1
```

В `database.yml` указан owners таблицы, и у него стоит  `GRANT ALL privileges ON DATABASE`

в логах приложения:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

Comment: а из `rails dbconsole` доступ есть (в продакшн окружении)?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду непосредственно production где развернуто приложение, или где я staging хочу развернуть?

Comment: я имею ввиду `-e production`

Comment: Накатывать миграции поверх бэкапа?.. но зачем вообще это может понадобиться? Может, стоит убрать этот абзац из вопроса вообще?

Comment: я наоборот не накатывал, понимаю что это не нужно. просто объяснил почему миграции не делал.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, есть доступ

Comment: Как проверили наличие доступа? Подключились, запустили вышеуказанный запрос?

Comment: @D-side да, сделал RAILS_ENV=production rails dbconsole

Comment: @dmitriy а запрос из вашего вопроса выполнили в ней?

Comment: @D-side `grant all` вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @dmitriy я имею в виду запрос, который как раз упал. `SELECT  "site_configs".* FROM "site_configs"  LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60967/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-d-side).